# Can't have the value of P for this recurrence using Akra Bazzi method

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence, divide-and-conquer

Using Akra Bazzi method for this recurrence,

[image]

Here, [image]

Now, I can't get the value of P. How can I solve this recurrence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case we know that the value of P would be less than 1.
That means value of P would be less than the order of g(x). Hence we can say that the complexity would be θ(g(x)) i.e. θ(n).

Refer this https://youtu.be/Kqf0uO0oV6s?t=4571